# Replace text using regular expressions js vanilla

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace the text of an input. If I enter this value (11111111), the output format should be (1,111,111-1). I have no idea how to do this using js vanilla. I am trying to use regex and replace but I'm very confused.

```
let regExp = /^[1-9].\d{3}.\d{3}-\d{1}$/g;  
let newInput = input.replace(regExp, '$1,');
console.log( newInput);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is for the match, which must match the input string. Use the replacement pattern to reformat the output:

```js
let input = '11111111'
let regExp = /^(\d)(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d)$/g;  
let newInput = input.replace(regExp, '$1,$2,$3-$4');
console.log( newInput);
```

Comment: It work perfect, thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: How could I admit an input with the correct format? Admith both 11111111 and 1,111,111-1

Comment: Try add optional separator `/^(\d),?(\d{3}),?(\d{3})-?(\d)$/`

Comment: nope. maybe and if with .match. It´s for validation